# Artifact issues with Wowza and GoogleTV: PE's result check pointer is null

Tags: google-tv, wowza

I'm streaming live feeds from Wowza to GoogleTV boxes via HLS. I'm having a lot of issues with artifacts, the kind you see if you lose packets, where part of the screen lags behind and doesn't get updated properly until the next key frame arrives. It's the same on the Visio, HiSense and Sony, with latest updates (GoogleTV FW 3.2 and Wowza 3.5.2). Watching the same streams in VLC or on an a Nexus 4/7 works great.

This is what I get from logcat:

```
[ 03-13 16:07:15.343   678:0xb3c W/MVBerlinVideoEngine36 ]
  ** empty vid_meta!!!


[ 03-13 16:07:15.423   678:0x2f1 E/MVBerlinVideoEngine36 ]
  !! PE's result check pointer is null line = 536
```

The media is a live stream, encoded by VLC.

```
vlc udp://@239.0.0.2:10021 --sout "#transcode{deinterlace,deinterlace-mode=linear,acodec=aac,ab=160,vcodec=h264,venc=x264{profile=high,level=4.1,preset=fast}}:rtp{mux=ts,dst=192.168.100.10,port=10021}"
```

I have no idea where to continue to at this point. Can I get more information somehow? Is it most likely a decoding issue, network issue (tried wired + several wifi gateways) or code issue?

Comment: Can you post some more info on your Wowza setup. Also details on the video you are streaming would be good. It sounds like there may be a bug here. What happens if you play the video from disk (eg. from a usb key or equiv.) Can you also post the HLS headers?

Comment: Wowza is pretty much off the shelf, can't think of any significant changes I've made. As for usb testing, vod works, live doesn't. Testing with big buck bunny, loading file directly works, loading via wowza vod works, streaming it from vlc via wowza doesn't. My normal stream is a mpeg2ts created by dvblast, transcoded by vlc. Updated question with encoding details. As for HLS headers, not sure how to extract these...

Answer (score 2):

This is a firmware bug on the device. You will not be able to work around this right now. Internal bug filed - you will need to wait for an update.

Comment: I know you wrote internal bug, but is there any chance there's a public tracker to folow the issue?

Comment: you can file one on googletv-issues and I will try to update it when there is more info - currently being looked at by the team

Answer (score 0):

We also often faced with the problem of freezing the bottom of the screen  especially when we broadcast mp4 files with strong motion and frequent scene changes. When you plan to update the software? Is there a downloadable beta version of GoogleTV in which this problem was fixed?